# MySql Case Query with select Count

Tags: mysql

I am writing a simple case statement where I return the value 1 if number of rows returned are 1 or more and 0 if nothing is found .

I am getting a Syntax error on listed below simple query

```
 SELECT CASE (select count(*) from account where account_id = 12 >0) then 1 else 0 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL returns `1` if a condition is *TRUE* and `0` if it is *FALSE*

```
SELECT count(*) >= 1
from account 
where account_id = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out I was missing the word when true in the query

```
 SELECT CASE (select count(*) from .account where account_id  = 12 >0) when true then 1 else 0 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 SELECT CASE (select count(*) from .account where account_id  = 12 >0) when true then 1 else 0 end;
```

only syntactically works, as you mistakenly compare 12 with 0. This is certainly an improvement:

```
 SELECT CASE ((select count(*) from .account where account_id  = 12) > 0) when true then 1 else 0 end;
```

However, why do you need to count all the records, when you can test for existence:

```
 SELECT CASE (exists (select 1 from .account where account_id  = 12)) when true then 1 else 0 end;
```

This last one will find the first such row if exists and return one if so, 0 otherwise.